# How does recursion work in the example below?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am a beginner and I am trying to understand how recursion works in this function. More specifically, I am confused why `console.log('end: ' + i);` is being executed when `return;` should exit the function once the `(i < 0)` condition is met.

I've not found an explanation anywhere else, can someone explain to me?

```
function foo(i) {
  if (i < 0)
    return;
  console.log('begin: ' + i);
  foo(i - 1);
  console.log('end: ' + i);
}
foo(3);
// Output:

// begin: 3
// begin: 2
// begin: 1
// begin: 0
// end: 0
// end: 1
// end: 2
// end: 3
```

Comment: `return` returns the innermost invocation, this doesn't affect all the other invocations.

Comment: because the functions are still in the stack and need to get out of it.. the return on i<0 takes care just for the last func then goes back to others to see what s  below and below is the console doesnt return anything so it defaults to undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `foo` will first execute with the argument of number 3 which you passed to it `foo(3)` it will then go into the memory/stack and and run its course.

Each time it stumbles onto itself/same function but with a decreased argument `foo(2) foo(1)`etc. it will accumulate those instances inside the stack.

Each recursion must have a stopping case, in your case that is when it reaches the first whole negative number which is -1. Since the last function or the first in the stack is now `foo(-1)` it will return nothing for it but this will **resolve** that function `foo(-1)` meaning you are left with `foo(0) foo(1) foo(2) foo(3)` to resolve because they are still in the stack/memory.

The first one to execute is `foo(0)` which will `console.log(0)` return undefined in the end since a function which does not explicitly have a return keyword returns undefined in JS. This will carry on until you empty your entire stack (get to `foo(3)`).

After your stack is empty the program terminates.